# sendmail fail to send HTML e-mail on oracle linux

Tags: sendmail, oracle-linux

I'm trying to send html formatted mail through sendmail function in oracle enterprise linux. I'm using following script and HTML format to send the mail. Which is working on ubuntu as expected. But on oracle linux it send the HTML as plane text.

```
cat cpu_alert.html | /usr/lib/sendmail -t
```

And the "cpu_alert.html" file will be like follows

```
From: donotreply@example.com
To: admin@example.com
Subject: CPU utilization heigh
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html

<h1>Mail body will be here</h1>
The mail body should start after one blank line from the header.
```

There are few similar post available on stackoverflow. But those suggestions not working in oracle Linux.

Comment: Could you post headers of the RECEIVED message?

Comment: I'm using outlook. How to get those headers?